# An example about namespace in C++

Tags: c++

```
namespace A::B {
  class MyClass{};
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this code does not compile?

Comment: Please add the error you are getting to your question.

Comment: Nested namespaces is a C++17 feature. Perhaps you did not enable the C++17 support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code uses nested namespaces, which are a C++17 feature. You probably get an error because your compiler doesn't support C++17, or you haven't configured it to understand C++17. The pre-C++17 version of your code would be

```
namespace A {
namespace B {
    class MyClass {};
}
}
```