# One example about inheritance in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

The following is a question about inheritance.

```
class A { 
public: 
    virtual string F() = 0;
};

class B: public A {
public: 
    string F() {
        return "B";
    }
};

int main() {
    B b; 
    A* ap = &b;
    cout << b.F() << ap->F();
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this code does not compile?

Comment: **-1**. Provided that `string` and `cout` are the entities in `namespace std`, there is nothing wrong with the code in question - as such more information is necessary.

Comment: [it does](https://ideone.com/oOw1iW).

Comment: Also fix your indentation.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: All compilers that I've ever used have shown an error message when they fail to compile something. Did yours not show an error?

Comment: This question's structure looks eerily similar to (the original version of) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49586228/an-example-about-namespace-in-c). What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the headers which define the `string` type, and `cout` stream, which both live in the `std` namespace:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class A {
  public:virtual string F()=0;
};

class B: public A {
  public: string F() {
              return "B";
          }
};

int main(){
  B b; A* ap=&b;
  cout<<b.F()<<ap->F();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @HDJEMAI - thanks for editing to match your improved formatting of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include header files at the start of the code with std namespace.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
```